# Trigger Jenkins Multi-Branch Pipeline from GitLab push

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-plugins

I run a Gitlab and a Jenkins server locally. I connected those two using the gitlab-branch-source plugin. For every repository in gitlab i create a multibranch-pipeline job in jenkins. When a user pushes code, I want the corresponding job to be executed.

I'v tried a solution suggestend in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490150/how-to-remotely-trigger-jenkins-multibranch-pipeline-project-build/39490151#39490151) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40979405/how-to-trigger-jenkins-multi-branch-pipeline-with-gitlab-webhook). Both of them don't seem to work.

In the gitlab server settings on the jenkins server I've set the check at "Manage Web Hooks". The personal access token which is used for the integration has the scopes "api, sudo".

What else could I try?