# How to trigger a Jenkins multibranch pipeline when code change is pushed to GitHub

Tags: github, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

I have a Jenkins job (`multibranch pipeline`) setup for a GitHub repo. I want to trigger that job automatically whenever there is a change pushed to that Git repo. How can I achieve this using a `Jenkinsfile`?

I want to avoid any config change in the Jenkins job such as `Poll SCM` etc. For multibranch pipeline there is no such option as `Build whenever a change is pushed to GitHub`

Comment: this is what should happen if you configure your mbp. Add your source (git) and fill in the repo endpoint. Make sure there is a Jenkinsfile at root level and set `build configuration` > `mode` to `by Jenkinsfile`. Then make sure that github trigegrs jenkins (via project > settings > services > Jenkins (github plugin))

Comment: @Rik Unfortunately this does not seem to be working. I have covered all the points you mentioned. This worked when I added `poll scm` option but that's what I want to avoid. Just to add one more detail - I am using Jenkins Enterprise and we have a folder there to create jobs related to our team.

Comment: at my work we have this configured for gitlab, and that works. I assume github is the same. If I have Some time later today I will check if I can get it working for github and then post a screenshot

Comment: Thanks for your help @Rik, much appreciated!

Comment: If I use the `Git` (not `Github`) plugin, it works [config](http://pasteboard.co/vujxO7nHa.png) and [branch-index](http://pasteboard.co/vui1xj62N.png)

Comment: Sorry no luck! I am also using Git plugin with almost same config not sure what have I done wrong :(

Comment: Your jenkins instance is not behind a firewall by accident, which doesn't allow github to push to the url?

Comment: We are using enterprise versions of Jenkins and GitHub.

Comment: I am not fafmiliar with those, but are they very different?

Comment: Maybe a little difference, paid features added :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remotely trigger Jenkins multibranch pipeline project build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490150/how-to-remotely-trigger-jenkins-multibranch-pipeline-project-build)

Comment: @Rik my job configuration (Git, not GitHub) doesn't allow to define build triggers. There's no "Build Triggers" section, only "Scan Multibranch Pipeline Triggers". Are you sure you were testing with a pipeline project? We're on v2.100 from 2018-01-03.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your job "reacting" to events from your GitHub, set the job build trigger to "Poll SCM", but do **not** specify a schedule, as described on [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45557025/1645517).

For declarative Jenkinsfile, this means:

```
pipeline {
  triggers {
    pollSCM('') // Enabling being build on Push
  }
  ...
}
```

Further readings:

- https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#triggers

Comment: lol
In my experience, this is one out of some more possible problems/solutions when getting a Jenkins-job triggered by GitHub.

Comment: any chance you can take a look at my latest question?

Comment: I did have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52991939/multibranch-pipeline-github-webhook, but I don't have an idea.

Comment: In jenkins docs you sent: . For Pipelines which are integrated with a source such as GitHub or BitBucket, triggers may not be necessary as webhooks-based integration will likely already be present.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this descriptive pipeline script to auto build your pipeline whenever new changes are pushed to github

```
pipeline{
   agent any     
     triggers {
        githubPush()
      }
   ...
 }
```

Also you should enable the github webhook with relavant secret tokens.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest option by far (that I'm aware of) is to remotely tell the Jenkins Git plugin that there's a new commit for a defined repository. However, this will not trigger Jenkins to start a job immediately. What happens is that the Git plugin starts (re-)indexing the specific repository. If changes are detected the Jenkins job is then started.

From your repository (GitHub, GitLab, etc.) you should trigger the following URL:

`http://my-jenkins-host/git/notifyCommit?url=git@gitlab.example.com:group/repository.git&delay=0sec`

The value for `url` must match the SCM URL you configured in the Jenkins job (Git plugin)!

Gotcha: it may be that your Jenkins is **not** deployed under the root context (`/`) in which case the URL would be `http://my-jenkins-host/context-path/git/...`