# Jenkins Pipeline job isn't triggered on GitHub push

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, webhooks

I've created Jenkins Pipline job and want it to be triggered on my GitHub repo push event.

I've added repo url to job config and checked "trigger on push option":
[image]

I've also added GitHub token with needed rights to jenkins configure Github section: [image]

In Github repo I've enabled webhook for my Jenkins server:
[image]

And after all steps still nothing is triggered after push to my GitHub repo.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on and why Jenkins doesn't trigger configured pipeline job?

Comment: Are you sure Jenkins machine IP is visible to github? Since your settings look ok

Comment: @Olia , Yeah, ofc, it's public amazone IP, If I setup webhook in my repo manually wo/ Github services support, then I can see that my server response 200 status code per each push action for request from GitHub. But nothing happens on Jenkins side.

Comment: I guess, you may take a look at this issue: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-35132 (Also note that the job has to be executed manually one time in order for the push trigger and the git repo to be registered)

Comment: Sry guys, already resolved the issue, such pipeline job must be run manually once after configuration. That's all.

Comment: In the above comment I suggested to do the same)

Answer (score 13):

Solution mentioned by OP in a comment is correct.

Assuming you have a Github webhook for your Jenkins set up correctly and accessible (can be verified in the Github UI), you need to start the build manually once. Upon completion of the build, changes in the repository will automatically start new builds.

---

A note from [user8888](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7489488/user8888):

> You actually need to **manually start** the build and the **build must be successful**. A failed build won't do anything.

Comment: This was not obvious to me so to clarify for others - you actually need to manually start the build and the build must actually be **successful**. A failed build won't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Just to verify if those comments above are unclear. If you can verify in the jenkins log that the job is actually being poked. You just need to make sure that it was built successfully before in order to move beyond the stage poked.

Answer (score -3):

With Github hook trigger for GITScm polling, you need to enable "Poll SCM" option because github push triggers git polling to verify if there is a new change and then runs the build if a change is found.
You can keep the cron schedule empty.[Github webhook with scm poll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqDsd.png)

Comment: This is incorrect. As in the comments above, a manual run is necessary to make Jenkins pick up the webhook.

Comment: The correct option is to correctly configure the "GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling" option. The "Poll SCM" option warns, "Note that this is going to be an expensive operation for CVS, as every polling requires Jenkins to scan the entire workspace and verify it with the server. Consider setting up a "push" trigger to avoid this overhead"